# When is a vector bundle morphism a vector bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

When does a morphism $f:E'\to E$ of vector bundles over the same base $B$ make $E'$ a vector bundle over $E$? Definitely $f$ has to be surjective, and this seems like it is also sufficient. Because any point of $B$ has a neighborhood $U$ over which $E'$ and $E$ are both trivial. Then it seems to me that $E'$ is trivialized over the open set $p^{-1}(U)\subseteq E$, where $p$ is the projection $E\to B$.

(Maybe it's a simple question, but just wanted to double check).

Comment: If $B=\{*\}$ is just a point, then $E,E'$ are just vector spaces. Now if $f:E'\to E$ is a linear map, and $e\in E$, what is the vector space structure on $f^{-1}(e)$ ? What would be the zero element ? You need to put an additional structure which won't be canonical, and in certain context may not even exists. Indeed, if $f:E'\to E$ is to be a vector bundle, you need in particular (that's enough actually) the zero section : $s:E\to E'$. So you need $f$ to split. If you are talking about algebraic or holomorphic bundle, such a splitting does not necessarily exist.

Comment: Dear @Roland, you are right, it needs a splitting, but are you sure that the structure really depends on the splitting? It seems to me that different splittings give rise to isomorphic structures.

Comment: @Ben Up to isomorphism, yes different splitting give isomorphic structures and even canonically isomorphic structure. Yet these structures are different. So $E'\to E$ is not a vector bundle in a unique way (and sometimes not a vector bundle at all). In fact $E'$ is a bundle of affine spaces parallels to $\ker f$. The choice of the origin completely determines the vector space structure. Given two such choices represented by two sections $s,s'$, then the translation by $s-s'$ is indeed an isomorphism of the vector space structure given by $s$ to the one given by $s'$.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your comment. I understand what you mean. Do you know of any cases in which we can be ensured a splitting? By the way, I mean algebraic bundles.

Comment: Also, I thought any variety is compact (because Noetherian), so Ben's comment would suggest $f$ splits?

Comment: No in algebraic geometry, almost no surjective morphism of vector bundle splits. Of course they are criterion, for example if $B$ is affine. But if this is what you are looking for, you should ask another question (because this is quite different from the one you asked) and be more specific about your situation (because you might get only generalities which doesn't apply to your problem).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true. [No, not quite, see below.] It's a bit easier to see if $B$ is paracompact, say, since then any surjective vector bundle surjection on $B$ splits, i.e., $E'\cong E\oplus \ker(f)$ such that $f$ gets identified with the projection and this is the pull-back of the vector bundle $\ker(f)\to B$ along $E\to B$.

**Edit:** Roland is right. If $f$ is not split, then it's wrong. On the other hand, every splitting gives rise to a vector bundle structure, unique up to isomorphism.